# Copy rows of data from one sheet to another, where the destination sheets are named by dates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have information stored on one sheet of an Excel 2010 workbook, one column of which contains dates. I want a macro which will group this information by date and copy it to other sheets in the same workbook, which I have previously set up and named by those dates.

So I have this information on a sheet called "Source":

```
Date         First Name  Last Name  Hair Colour
01/02/2011   Bob         Jones      Brown
02/05/2011   Geoff       Smith      Red
03/09/2010   Craig       Hamilton   Blond
02/05/2011   Chris       Wazowski   Brown
05/06/2011   Steve       Mac        Blond
03/09/2010   Tom         Lounds     Brown
```

And I have four other sheets, named: "01 Feb 2011", "02 May 2011", "03 Sep 2010", and "05 June 2011"

I want a macro which will copy the heading, and entire rows from the "Source" sheet which have these dates over to their corresponding sheets.

Data is continually being added to the "Source" sheet, so this is an action I will need to repeat frequently.

I know there is plenty of code on this site which show how to group and copy information over to other sheets by condition, but I haven't found one which works in just this way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to convert back and forth between a `Date` (data in your first column) and a `String` having the same format as your sheet names.

```
Dim d As Date
Dim sheetName As String

d = CDate("01/02/2011") ' or e.g. Range("A2").Value
sheetName = Format(d, "dd mmm yyyy")

Debug.Print sheetName ' 01 Feb 2011
```

As for the rest, as you point out yourself, a gazillion similar questions have been answered on this website and offer solutions to problems almost identical to yours. Once you've tried something, let us know if you have trouble with anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jean-Francois.

I found a solution which works beautifully, although I'm not entirely sure how or why:

```
Sub Update_Sheets()

'Formats dates
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngA As Range

Set rngA = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Range("A:A").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
rngA.NumberFormat = "@"
For Each rng In rngA
    rng.Value = Format(rng, "dd mmm yyyy")
Next rng


'Copies rows of data to the right sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet, source As Range, dest As Range
Dim daily As Worksheet
Set daily = Worksheets("Source")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> daily.Name Then
daily.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ws.Name
Set source = daily.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
Set dest = Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
source.Copy dest
End If
Next
daily.Range("A1").AutoFilter
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```